# Select Query in cursor FOR LOOP

Tags: oracle, plsql

Pretty new to Oracle, need help on this Procedure, using Oracle 11g

Sample table data (TAB1):

| ID | Amount | Currency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 300 | GBP |
| 15 | 500 | GBP |
| 20 | 100 | GBP |

1. Requirement is to select all the ID's from TAB1 based on currency and store it in a variable and later use these ID's in other select Queries within the same Stored Procedure.

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc (i_id IN VARCHAR, i_curr IN VARCHAR)
AS
   CURSOR GET_I IS
      SELECT ID, CURRENCY
        FROM TAB1
       WHERE CURRENCY = 'GBP';

   -- This will give me 3 ID's (10, 15 & 20) which I am storing in variable r_1 below.
   r_1  VARCHAR (5)       : NULL;
BEGIN
   OPEN GET_I;

   LOOP
      FETCH GET_I INTO r_1;

      IF GET_I%NOTFOUND
      THEN
         EXIT;
      ---In the below ELSE PART can we run a select query using the value stored in r_1??
      --ELSE
      --Data stored in r_1 to be used in further select queries in later part and output of the below
      --be returned as SYS_REFCURSOR;
      --BELOW two lines gives error
      --FOR I in r_1 (
      --SELECT ID FROM TAB2 WHERE TAB2.ID=r_1);

      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE GET_ID;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks you want to use a nested `FOR` loop.

I'd suggest you to use cursor FOR loops - they are easier to maintain as you don't have to declare cursor variable (by the way, in your case it wouldn't work anyway as you'd like to store both `ID` and `CURRENCY` into a scalar `R_1` variable), open the cursor, pay attention about exiting the loop and closing the cursor. In a cursor FOR loop, Oracle does all that for you.

Here's an example:

Sample table:

```
SQL> select * from tab1;

        ID     AMOUNT CUR
---------- ---------- ---
        10        300 GBP
        15        500 GBP
        20        100 GBP
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure myproc as
  2  begin
  3    for cur_id in (select id from tab1) loop
  4      dbms_output.put_line('ID = ' || cur_id.id);
  5      for cur_other in (select amount, currency
  6                        from tab1
  7                        where id = cur_id.id    --> use ID fetched in outer loop
  8                       )
  9      loop
 10        dbms_output.put_line(cur_other.amount ||' - '|| cur_other.currency);
 11      end loop;
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec myproc;
ID = 10
300 - GBP
ID = 15
500 - GBP
ID = 20
100 - GBP

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

How to return a **refcursor**?

```
SQL> create or replace procedure myproc (par_id  in tab1.id%type,
  2                                      par_rc out sys_refcursor) as
  3  begin
  4    for cur_id in (select id
  5                   from tab1
  6                   where id = par_id
  7                  ) loop
  8
  9      open par_rc for select amount, currency
 10                      from tab1
 11                      where id = cur_id.id;
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /

Procedure created.

SQL> var l_rc refcursor
SQL>
SQL> exec myproc(10, :l_rc);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print l_rc

    AMOUNT CUR
---------- ---
       300 GBP

SQL>
```

Comment: Wow !!!! this looks so neat, let me quickly execute this. Also can we assign the output result set to a SYS_REFCURSOR? and I am trying only to store the id in scaler variable not both. ID would suffice

Comment: this is not giving expected output, the `dbms_output.put_line('ID = ' || cur_id.id);` prints only 1st value instead of all the values

Comment: What I posted is an example which shows you the way *how to do it*. What you'll actually do depends on you. Therefore, feel free to modify code I posted so that it displays whatever you want. As of refcursor: sure, you can assign output to it. As it is a procedure, it should have an OUT parameter whose datatype will be SYS_REFCURSOR.

Comment: Unable to frame it, would you please help me with the code ?

Comment: Code for what, exactly?

Comment: to assign the output to a REFCURSOR